# Why expo is showing Loading DevTools Error

Tags: react-native, expo

My react native app is showing error when using `expo-cli`:

> Error loading DevTools
> ,No scheme specified for development client

picture:

[image]

I am using `expo` version 44 And `react-native` version 0.64 ,also I have used `expo init` in order to create my project.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to run:

```
expo install expo-dev-client
```

Then, for Android:

```
expo run:android
```

or for IOS:

```
expo run:ios
```

Since config plugins will let you customize your project from JavaScript without ever needing to directly modify XCode or Android Studio projects.

More details here
https://docs.expo.dev/development/getting-started/